# tableview : Data overlapped while delete the row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my iPhone application...

In table view I am deleting the row...

updating the array from which I am feeding the table....

Reloading to data row....

[image]

x

**Yes but Data which is deleted is proper..**

Cell for Row at Index Path....

I have just added One Label to the row...
While deleting the row

I am just deleting the data from array

And Updating the count of the rows(decrementing)...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            }


            //Get the Log Id for the sections. From Section Array
            int logID=0;
            if(indexPath.row==0)
            {
                NSLog(@"Time Array %@",timeArray);
                  logID=[[[sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"logID"] intValue];
                  NSPredicate *p=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"logID==%d",logID];
                  fillRows=nil;
                  fillRows= [[timeArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p] mutableCopy];
            }

        //Show Current Time.
        //"If condition for not to go for Array Index Out of Bound".
        if(indexPath.row<[fillRows count])
        {
        //Log CurrentTime    
            cell.textLabel.text=[[fillRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"logCurrentTime"];
        //Log Duration.   
            UILabel *lblDuration=[[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 11, 60, 21)] autorelease] ;

      lblDuration.text=[[fillRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"logDuration"];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblDuration];
        }

            return cell;
        }
```

EDIT ::Question of Overlapping the Labels Which has been patiallly solved.
Because now the label is not overlapped but 
When I remove any row then that rows' label remain same 
---> the last row is not shown in the table.

**[See this link Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664212/table-view-could-not-delete-the-custom-label-in-custom-cell)**

Comment: please show code of cellForRow...

Comment: see the link  answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664212/table-view-could-not-delete-the-custom-label-in-custom-cell aswered by me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you keep adding a new label to the cell each time the cell is drawn.

try moving the following code into the `if (cell == nil) {..} block`

```
UILabel *lblDuration=[[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 11, 60, 21)] autorelease] ;
[cell.contentView addSubview:lblDuration];
```

Comment: Did you, by any chance, move the lblDuration.text = ... part as well? That one should not be inside the if (cell == nil) { ... } block

Comment: How do you delete an item from the array?

Comment: Just getting stuffs from indexPath matching with an array..but it is working fine ...

Comment: see the link I have got some answer....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664212/table-view-could-not-delete-the-custom-label-in-custom-cell

Answer (score 1):

It's because `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns an unused cell that you have created from previous call to `cellForRow...` delegate. If you are going to add a label to cell, you should do it after cell `init` line and including tag for the label so we can find the label later in the cell. The code should be something like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *lblDuration= [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        lblDuration=[[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 11, 60, 21)] autorelease] ;
        lblDuration.tag = 1;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblDuration];
    }


    //Get the Log Id for the sections. From Section Array
    int logID=0;
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
         NSLog(@"Time Array %@",timeArray);
          logID=[[[sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"logID"] intValue];
          NSPredicate *p=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"logID==%d",logID];
          fillRows=nil;
          fillRows= [[timeArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p] mutableCopy];
    }

    // Show Current Time.
    //"If condition for not to go for Array Index Out of Bound".
    if(indexPath.row<[fillRows count])
    {
    //Log CurrentTime    
        cell.textLabel.text=[[fillRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"logCurrentTime"];
    //Log Duration.   


        lblDuration.text=[[fillRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"logDuration"];

    }
    return cell;
}
```

Sorry that I did not try to compile this but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When you are deleting the row... you also have to delete the `UILabel` that you have added on that cell... You have to Handle that `UILabel` explicitly... as you have created a new view on a cell...

so just handle the cell delete row method if you are using that to delete.... and in that method also delete the `UILabel`... or just use `[tableView reload]` data.. which will do that automatically....

Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Yes I have done that but some how [tableview deleterowatindexpath] was giving me a signal abort... So I need to make some arrangements....other than that....Thanks Love